# Set stream state to communicate error in formatted output operator (operator<<)

Tags: c++, operators, outputstream

I believe it is a best practice to set the failbit on an input stream when a given input is not usable. However I wonder why I don't find evidence to do the same on ostreams.

For example [cppreference](https://https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) has the following examples for overloading operators << and >>.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
    // write obj to stream
    return os;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, T& obj)
{
    // read obj from stream
    if( /* T could not be constructed */ )
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

**Question: I wonder if one should also set the failbit on the output stream (if applicable).**

Please consider the following example:

```
enum class enumeration
{
    ONE,
    TWO
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const enumeration& e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case enumeration::ONE:
            os << "1";
            break;
        case enumeration::TWO:
            os << "2";
            break;
        default: 
            os.setstate(std::ios::failbit); // <-- line in question
            break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Is the line in question reasonable or not? 
(I put a working example here [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/8c4ro).)

In the end I wonder whether I can, should or avoid setting the failbit on ostreams and why.

Comment: You try to combine validation and output in the same operation. That breaks [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: I am bit confused by the example from cppreference, as in general it is not absolutely necessary to construct a `T`, i mean you get already an instance passed..., i guess it is just meant to demonstrate a use-case for setting the failbit, or maybe the comment is just misleading

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude who else should set the `failbit` if not the `operator<<` ?

Comment: @user463035818 I'd argue that validation of the value should happen independently of the output operation. Preferably as part of possible input or other place when the variable is assigned to. The only error from `operator<<` should be related to the output itself. With the code shown by the OP, it's impossible to say if the error is from a validation error, or from failure to write to the output stream.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah ok get it. Anyhow I dont understand how the `default` can be reached for the scoped enum unless one deliberately tries to do something wrong, in which case you just get what you asked for

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude tried to wrap up the comments in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarizing my conclusions from comments (thanks to Some programmer dude for the input)...

You are mixing two concerns that you better keep seperated:

a) the value of the enum could be invalid

b) streaming to `os` can fail

One can argue that a) does not really belong into the `operator<<` overload. If you want to make sure that the enum is valid, then you want to check this maybe also in other places not only when streaming it. Actually you should do it before, to be able to detect an error as soon as possible, not only when it reaches the user/outside world. On the other hand, from the top of my head I dont know how you could reach the `default` with a scoped enum unless you deliberately try to do something wrong. In that case you just get what you deserve. Don't be overprotective.

For b) you do not need to do anything extra in your code. If

```
 os << "1";
```

does fail, then this call will already set the failbit for you.

TL;DR: You probably do not need the check in the `operator<<`. If you think you need the check then `operator<<` is still not the right place to put it.

Comment: Agreed. In case the value of the variable is read from the outside it should be checked exactly than. In case the value is set internally (or it was already checked on input) it would overprotective to check it (again).

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice for the case you've described is to write some representation of an invalid value.  There's usually no need to flag it as an error.  For example you could write "? (42)" if the numeric value 42 appears.  Or perhaps just "42", if you prefer to be able to round-trip the text back to an enum easily using `operator >>`.